# different hash construction processes in Perl

Tags: perl

I noticed a hash object was once defined as in the following:

```
 my  %data = ();
 $data{file}  = $file;
 $data{concept} = $#row;
 $data{line1} {$cell[0]} = $cell[1];
```

What does this hash construction process try to achieve? Or what is the difference between

```
$data{concept} = $#row;
```

and

```
$data{line1} {$cell[0]} = $cell[1];
```

?

Comment: That is not well-formed Perl.

Comment: I believe it is now, but the question is still vague.  @bit-question, please confirm that the edited code is really what you meant.

Comment: Your question is far from clear. Why do you think the code tries to achieve something other than what it does achieve? Why do you think the two statements are similar?

Comment: @ikegami: I'm guessing he's just new at Perl and haven't encountered hash references or nested hashes before.

Comment: @flesk, Yes, perhaps he meant to ask "what does this code do?" But he didn't ask anything remotely similar to that, so I asked him to clarify rather than spending 30 minutes answering a question he might not be asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = "contents of my file";
my @row = qw(some random data);
my @cell = qw(key value);

my %data = ();
$data{file}  = $file;
$data{concept} = $#row;
$data{line1} {$cell[0]} = $cell[1];

print Dumper \%data;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'file' => 'contents of my file',
      'line1' => {
                   'key' => 'value'
                 },
      'concept' => '2'
};
```

I think `$data{line1} {$cell[0]}` is better written as `$data{line1}{$cell[0]}` or (my preference) `$data{line1}->{$cell[0]}`.

I included the scalar `$file` and the arrrays `@row` and `@cell` to demonstrate what your code means.

```
$data{file} = $file;
```

adds the contents of `$file` to your hash with the key `file`.

```
$data{concept} = $#row;
```

adds the last index of `@row` to your hash with the key `concept`. In my example the last index is `2`, since the indexes in `@row` are `0`, `1` and `2`.

```
$data{line1} {$cell[0]} = $cell[1];
```

adds a hash ref to your hash with the key `line1` (through autovivification) and adds the element `$cell[1]` to this hash ref with the key `$cell[0]`. Autovivification in this case means that Perl associates `line1` with a hash ref and creates it, because you're accessing it with `{$cell[0]}`. That saves you the trouble of having to write:

```
$data{line} = {};
$data{line}{$cell[0]} = $cell[1];
```